# How do I stretch the ball with top and bottom bone?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints, parent

How can I stretch the ball with the top bone and bottom bone? I tried using a constraint but I did not get the desired result. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/47c0bae49264f6f342c11e4e3cc90e0220221009152932/002d13db072aee3815a6db8d87fe18e620221009153041/774901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your "Armature" delete the "Bone" (in edit mode).

In object mode, select the ball, shift-select the armature -> CTRL-p -> automatic weights.

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris!

Comment: You are welcome